# Is it possible to show only certain fields from Kendo datasource in a Kendo grid, but show them all in the "add" popup?

Tags: javascript, html, web, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI DataSource that has 10 fields in it. I want to use a Kendo Grid for the CRUD operations on the data. All 10 fields are required to be entered, but I only want to display a few of them in the actual Grid control. Displaying all 10 would make the Grid very large and bloated-looking.

If I use the Grid's built-in "popup" editing feature, can I make it so the user enters all of the fields in the popup but only some of them display in the actual grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns are not re-sizable I ended up just setting the width attribute to 1. This will work for my purposes.